# How can I check with JQuery if a checkbox is checked and if so add a class to the parent label?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like, on load of the page, to check if a checkbox is :checked Then if it is, add a class to the label. I currently have the following script but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').is(':checked') {
        $(this).parent('label').toggleClass('label--active');
    });
});
```

My HTML is:

```
<label class="container-checkbox" for="checkOne">
    <span class="checkbox-label">Option one</span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkOne">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

I can not change the DOM order as these are custom checkboxes.

Comment: `$('input').is(':checked')` results in a boolean, your syntax here is like: `true { do stuff }` rather than an actual conditional statement like `if(true){do stuff}`

Comment: Also the round bracket on line 4 of your JS does not have a purpose.

Comment: Better to get the input by ID than tag because if you have a few other inputs on the page, you will be taking them too.

Comment: `$("input:checked").closest("label").addClass(...`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let checkboxone = document.getElementById('checkOne');
  checkboxone.addEventListener('change',function() {
    checkboxone.parentNode.classList.toggle('label--active');
  });
});
```

How does is work?

Everytime when the checkbox is clicked, the class 'label--active' will be added / removed.